# Conversion failed when converting varchar value to datatype bit

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add a new user to my database, but I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@actief' to data type bit.'

I don't understand why because `Actief` is of type `Bit` in my database.

I tried doing the change below, but it didn't solve anything

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@actief", SqlDbType.Bit);
```

Code:

```
public void InsertUser(Gebruiker user)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRING;
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    // set Connection Property  of Command object
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Gebruiker (Naam, Voornaam, Rol, Actief, Adres, Gemeente, Land, Functie) " +
                "VALUES ('@naam', '@voornaam', '@rol', '@actief', '@adres', '@gemeente', '@land', '@functie')";

    // assign values
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", user.Naam);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voornaam", user.Voornaam);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rol", user.Rol);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actief", user.Actief);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adres", user.Adres);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gemeente", user.Gemeente);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@land", user.Land);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@functie", user.Functie);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@actief", 1); send 1 instead of true.

Comment: This might be a good read for you. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Larnu finally proof that you are human. :)

Comment: Oh, I dunno about that @SeanLange...

Comment: I tried using  cmd.Parameters.Add("@actief", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = user.Actief; but it didnt solve anything..

Comment: Remove the single quoute around the parameter names in your command text

Comment: with ('@naam'...) you are sending the literal string "@naam", not the parameter value, must be (@naam...) instead

Answer (score 2):

Your insert command is all wrong - you need to **remove** all those single quotes from the SQL variables in the `VALUES()` section.

Try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Gebruiker (Naam, Voornaam, Rol, Actief, Adres, Gemeente, Land, Functie) " +
                  "VALUES (@naam, @voornaam, @rol, @actief, @adres, @gemeente, @land, @functie)";
```

With the single quotes, you're sending **string literals** (instead of the **values** of those variables!) into your `INSERT` command - and it's no big surprise that T-SQL **cannot convert** `'@actief'` to a `BIT` value.....